# How to remove inbound attachments from message property?

Tags: mule

I m using a html form which allows user to enter the details and choose a file to be sent as an attachment with an email via smtp connector in mule. I m using encoding type as- enctype="multipart/form-data" in my html form with method as "post". So all my html fields are coming as inbound attachments and they are being sent as separate 8 attachments in the mail.

Out of the 8 inbound attachments i want to drop 7 attachments and send only one attachment that is the file (highlighted with green) via email. How can i achieve this? Which transformer i should use?

[mule message structure image][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9fYu.png

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I found solution. First, you need to copy interesting attachment from inbound to outbound (use copy-attachment tag) and after that you should use transformer email:object-to-mime-transformer with attribute useInboundAttachments set to false. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you can drag and drop Attachment transformer after you receive all the attachments and then select Copy Attachment and give value as `#[message.inboundAttachments.'file']`.

Same to remove you can drag and drop Attachment Transformer and then select RemoveAttchment and then using MEL give attachment name.

`#[message.inboundAttachments.'subject']`

Hope this helps you !

Comment: `<remove-attachment attachmentName="#[message.inboundAttachments.'Category']" doc:name="Remove inbound attachment Category"/>` This is not working for me, I am using Mule 3.8